# How to filter key/values in javascript with a particular suffix in an object?

Tags: javascript

I have a object:

```
{
a_suff:"Something"
b_suff: "Value",
c: "Value",
d: "Value,
e_suff: "Value"
}
```

I want to have a function that returns be all the ones that end in "_suff". What is the best way to do that?

Right now I do:

```
function getFilterKeys(filter) {
    var filtered = {};
    for(var key in myobject) {
      if(key.endsWith(filter)) {
         filtered[key] = myobject[key];
      }
    }
    return filtered;
}
```

Hoping for an easier way or some built in prototype method.

Comment: With the edit including the code: that code is sufficient, with the caveat that it may enumerate properties on the prototypes (use a hasOwnProperty guard if this matters).. all changes would be opinionated in some fashion - use Array enumeration methods, use Object.keys, use lodash, use a higher-order function, etc. There is, however, *no standard* `Object.filter` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method here is about as simple as you can get. You're already using a new string method, `endsWith`, which is part of ES2015. Before that, you'd need to do extra work or define a helper function. Because you're filtering out certain properties, you need to iterate over all the keys, which means O(n) is the best you can do.